# How to sum rows by specific text in large data frame in R

Tags: r

So I have a large data set containing over 200 columns.

In the Data set (df) each entry is by date which makes the data looks like this

```
Name    Passes  Goal    
Jack    7       1   
Jack    4       2   
Ali     10      1
John    5       5
```

I would like it to sum values by the name of the person without me having to input the names (there are over 100 different names)
So it kind looks like this:

```
Name    Passes  Goal    
Jack    11      3   
Ali     10      1
John    5       5
```

How would I do this on r?

Comment: you should include a reproducible example. You can use dput() to make your dataset available.

Comment: table may do it but it without some example data it is difficult to tell.

Comment: just edited it for it to make sense

Comment: Just use `aggregate` or one of the many aggregation functions available within R or via packages (data.table, dplyr, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

Taking your original posted htlm-data and reading it via `rvest` (see below)
You can do the following:

```
dat <- doc %>% html_table() %>% `[[`(1)
colnames(dat) <- dat[1,]
dat <- dat[-1,]
dat[,2:3] <- lapply(dat[,2:3], as.numeric)
aggregate(.~Date, FUN = sum, data=dat)
```

Results in:

```
  Date Passes Goals
1  Ali      7     1
2 Jack     10     5
3 John     11     2
```

Read in the data:

```
require(rvest)
doc <- read_html('<div class="CSSTableGenerator" >
                <table >
          <tr>
          <td>
          Date
          </td>
          <td >
          Passes
          </td>
          <td>
          Goals
          </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td >
          John
          </td>
          <td>
          5
          </td>
          <td>
          1
          </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td >
          John
          </td>
          <td>
          6
          </td>
          <td>
          1
          </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td >
          Ali
          </td>
          <td>
          7
          </td>
          <td>
          1
          </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td >
          Jack
          </td>
          <td>
          10
          </td>
          <td>
          5
          </td>
          </tr>
          </table>
          </div>')
```

Comment: ?? What is all of this "rvest" stuff for?

Comment: This was his original question.... But he changed it - fast enough so it does not show up in the question-edits.
I thought his data has not changed so i post the "full" answer anyways...

Comment: It was my first post, wasnt sure how to format and make tables. But thanks alot for your answer, seems to work!

Comment: You only need the last line `aggregate(.~Date, FUN = sum, data=dat)` if you read in the data as `Matteo Felici` suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I think using  *dplyr*  package is easier. If you create your data.frame as

```
# install.packages("dplyr") only if not already installed
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(Name=c('Jack','Jack','Ali','John'), Passes=c(7,4,10,5), Goal=c(1,2,1,5))
```

you can first  *group_by*  the Name variable, then  *summarise*  the other variables:

```
res <- df %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarise(Tot_Passes=sum(Passes), Tot_Goals=sum(Goal))
```

Note: the %>% is a "pipe" operator, the result of the previous operation is the input for the next one.

Comment: Problem is there are many variables and names, typign them one by one will be very cubersome

Comment: @user5707770: Do you meant that there are many columns?  In that case, `dplyr` also provides `summarise_each`, so the code would be `df %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum))`